# Can I conditionally ignore properties based on the type of the parent's parent in Automapper?

Tags: automapper

Basically I would like to conditionally ignore a property based on the mapped parent.

An example:

Here are my DTOs:

```
public class PersonDTO
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<EmploymentDTO> Employments { get; set; }
   public List<HobbyDTO> Hobbies { get; set; }
}

public class EmploymentDTO
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public PersonDTO Person { get; set; }
}

public class HobbyDTO
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public PersonDTO Person { get; set; }
}
```

If I request a person then I would like to see its employments and hobbies returned but not an employment or hobby's persons. So I'd **don't** want to see the person objects in the following JSON:

```
{
  Id : 123,
  Name : "Person1",
  Employments [
  {
    Id : 1,
    Name : "Employment1",
    Person : { ... }
  },
  {
    Id : 2,
    Name : "Employment2",
    Person : { ... }
  }],
  Hobbies [
  {
    Id : 1,
    Name : "Hobby1",
    Person : { ... }
  },
  {
    Id : 2,
    Name : "Hobby2",
    Person : { ... }
  }]
}
```

Similarly, if employments was requested, I'd like the following JSON to be returned **without** the Employments and Hobbies properties on the person object:

```
{
  Id : 1,
  Name : "Employment1"
  Person : {
    Id : 123,
    Name : "Person1",
    Employments : [ ... ],
    Hobbies : [ ... ]
  }
}
```

Is there a way of doing this with Automapper? I've played around with Ignore and Condition but not been able to achieve what I need. I suppose I need to ignore properties depending on what the parents parent object is.

Comment: Why not just use different destination types? That's what I typically do, and not try to re-use DTOs for different scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jimmy Bogard. I could but that would increase the complexity of the application and mean more maintenance. The above is only a simple model but if it was added to I imagine that the number of of DTO classes would grow exponentially.

Comment: I tend to create DTOs for each request/response (actually decreases complexity since I'm not trying to reuse anything). What are your models being used for?

Comment: Thanks for your interest @Jimmy Bogard. They're for an OData service for reporting to allow a report writer to query available database objects. Automapper is being used to convert models to DTOs. Because the OData library I'm using doesn't support expanding child objects/collections I'm having to return all sensible child collections with the requested parent..Although, it sounds like I need to look for another way of doing this...

Comment: I suppose another approach for me would be to only map child objects and collections that are eager fetched and to ignore any that are proxies. I'll look into doing that.

Comment: OData, I suspected as much! Have you looked at explicit expansion?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at explicit expansion? https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions#explicit-expansion

You can direct AutoMapper to only expand certain properties at runtime. It's available in the LINQ mode of AutoMapper.